# How to search some specific string or a word and there coordinates from a pdf document in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Pdfbox to search a word(or String) from a pdf file and I also want to know the coordinates of that word.
For example :- in a pdf file there is a string like "${abc}". I want to know the coordinates of this string.
I Tried some couple of examples but didn't get the result according to me.
in result it is displaying the coordinates of character.

Here is the Code

```
@Override
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
    for(TextPosition text : textPositions) {


        System.out.println( "String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," +
                text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale=" +
                text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space=" +
                text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" +
                text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getUnicode());

    }
}
```

I am using pdfbox 2.0

Comment: I've used IText in the past for this purpose. Works nicely. If you want I can show an example of that. Never used pdfbox so I can't help with that.

Comment: "*I Tried some couple of examples but didn't get the result according to me. in result it is displaying the coordinates of character.*" - But if you have the coordinates of each character, you can combine them and have the coordinates of your search term, can you not?

Comment: @mkl could you please explain how to combine them

Comment: First of all, does the `writeString` code fragment in your question output the characters in the correct order? If not, have you initialized the `PdfTextStripper` wirh `setSortByPosition(true)`?

Comment: yes @mkl the 'writeString' code fragment output the characters in the correct order and I have initialized the 'PDFTextStripper' with 'setSortByPosition(true)'.

Comment: Ok, in that case it should really be easy to stitch those `TextPosition` instances together. I'll look into that later. (I don't know whether I have time during the weekend.)

Comment: Thanks @mkl and I will wait for your answer :)

Comment: I'm currently trying to think of a smart way to do this. One question, though, can I assume the search term to be a part of a single word (up to the whole single word)? Or does the code have to cope with search terms which span multiple words on a single line? Or even on multiple lines? I ask because `PDFTextStripper` methods allow easy access to the positioning data inside individual words but make things more difficult when accessing the whole line, let alone multiple lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last method in which PDFBox' `PDFTextStripper` class still has text with positions (before it is reduced to plain text) is the method

```
/**
 * Write a Java string to the output stream. The default implementation will ignore the <code>textPositions</code>
 * and just calls {@link #writeString(String)}.
 *
 * @param text The text to write to the stream.
 * @param textPositions The TextPositions belonging to the text.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error when writing the text.
 */
protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
```

One should intercept here because this method receives pre-processed, in particular *sorted* `TextPosition` objects (if one requested *sorting* to start with).

(Actually I would have preferred to intercept in the calling method `writeLine` which according to the names of its parameters and local variables has all the `TextPosition` instances of a *line* and calls `writeString` once per `word`; unfortunately, though, PDFBox developers have declared this method private... well, maybe this changes until the final 2.0.0 release... *nudge, nudge*. **Update:** Unfortunately it has not changed in the release... *sigh*)

Furthermore it is helpful to use a helper class to wrap sequences of `TextPosition` instances in a `String`-like class to make code clearer.

With this in mind one can search for the variables like this

```
List<TextPositionSequence> findSubwords(PDDocument document, int page, String searchTerm) throws IOException
{
    final List<TextPositionSequence> hits = new ArrayList<TextPositionSequence>();
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
    {
        @Override
        protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
        {
            TextPositionSequence word = new TextPositionSequence(textPositions);
            String string = word.toString();

            int fromIndex = 0;
            int index;
            while ((index = string.indexOf(searchTerm, fromIndex)) > -1)
            {
                hits.add(word.subSequence(index, index + searchTerm.length()));
                fromIndex = index + 1;
            }
            super.writeString(text, textPositions);
        }
    };
    
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    stripper.setStartPage(page);
    stripper.setEndPage(page);
    stripper.getText(document);
    return hits;
}
```

with this helper class

```
public class TextPositionSequence implements CharSequence
{
    public TextPositionSequence(List<TextPosition> textPositions)
    {
        this(textPositions, 0, textPositions.size());
    }

    public TextPositionSequence(List<TextPosition> textPositions, int start, int end)
    {
        this.textPositions = textPositions;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public int length()
    {
        return end - start;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index)
    {
        TextPosition textPosition = textPositionAt(index);
        String text = textPosition.getUnicode();
        return text.charAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    public TextPositionSequence subSequence(int start, int end)
    {
        return new TextPositionSequence(textPositions, this.start + start, this.start + end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length());
        for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
        {
            builder.append(charAt(i));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public TextPosition textPositionAt(int index)
    {
        return textPositions.get(start + index);
    }

    public float getX()
    {
        return textPositions.get(start).getXDirAdj();
    }

    public float getY()
    {
        return textPositions.get(start).getYDirAdj();
    }

    public float getWidth()
    {
        if (end == start)
            return 0;
        TextPosition first = textPositions.get(start);
        TextPosition last = textPositions.get(end - 1);
        return last.getWidthDirAdj() + last.getXDirAdj() - first.getXDirAdj();
    }

    final List<TextPosition> textPositions;
    final int start, end;
}
```

To merely output their positions, widths, final letters, and final letter positions, you can then use this

```
void printSubwords(PDDocument document, String searchTerm) throws IOException
{
    System.out.printf("* Looking for '%s'\n", searchTerm);
    for (int page = 1; page <= document.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
    {
        List<TextPositionSequence> hits = findSubwords(document, page, searchTerm);
        for (TextPositionSequence hit : hits)
        {
            TextPosition lastPosition = hit.textPositionAt(hit.length() - 1);
            System.out.printf("  Page %s at %s, %s with width %s and last letter '%s' at %s, %s\n",
                    page, hit.getX(), hit.getY(), hit.getWidth(),
                    lastPosition.getUnicode(), lastPosition.getXDirAdj(), lastPosition.getYDirAdj());
        }
    }
}
```

For tests I created a small test file using MS Word:

[image: Sample file with variables]

The output of this test

```
@Test
public void testVariables() throws IOException
{
    try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Variables.pdf");
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);    )
    {
        System.out.println("\nVariables.pdf\n-------------\n");
        printSubwords(document, "${var1}");
        printSubwords(document, "${var 2}");
    }
}
```

is

```
Variables.pdf
-------------

* Looking for '${var1}'
  Page 1 at 164.39648, 158.06 with width 34.67856 and last letter '}' at 193.22, 158.06
  Page 1 at 188.75699, 174.13995 with width 34.58806 and last letter '}' at 217.49, 174.13995
  Page 1 at 167.49583, 190.21997 with width 38.000168 and last letter '}' at 196.22, 190.21997
  Page 1 at 176.67009, 206.18 with width 35.667114 and last letter '}' at 205.49, 206.18

* Looking for '${var 2}'
  Page 1 at 164.39648, 257.65997 with width 37.078552 and last letter '}' at 195.62, 257.65997
  Page 1 at 188.75699, 273.74 with width 37.108047 and last letter '}' at 220.01, 273.74
  Page 1 at 167.49583, 289.72998 with width 40.55017 and last letter '}' at 198.74, 289.72998
  Page 1 at 176.67778, 305.81 with width 38.059418 and last letter '}' at 207.89, 305.81
```

I was a bit surprised because `${var 2}` has been found if on a single line; after all, PDFBox code made me assume the method `writeString` I overrode only retrieves *words*; it looks as if it retrieves longer parts of the line than mere words...

If you need other data from the grouped `TextPosition` instances, simply enhance `TextPositionSequence` accordingly.

Comment: I need the coordinates of last character from each search word for example if I search for `${var 2}` then i only need the coordinates of `}`.

Comment: It is trivial to add access to the individual `TextPosition` instances in a `TextPositionSequence`, see my edit.

Comment: @AshokKanwal Does this answer sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: the code is not working properly. pleas check it below .

Comment: Check it below what?

Comment: @mkl Is it possible to serialize analyzed text (`TextPositionSequence` or something similar) for whole page so it can be de-serialized after and used directly? It can then be stored (file, DB) and called when we need to highlight some words on one page. We are having problems with big PDFs and `PDDocument.load()` is taking too long - we only need positions for one page.

Comment: The `TextPositionSequence` as is would not help as it is backed by objects in the loaded PDF (it refers to `TextPosition` which eventually refer to e.g. font objects inside the PDF). But obviously you can traverse a `TextPositionSequence` and store all the required information in a database. Considering, though, that you want to use this when you *"need to highlight some words on one page"*, you'll have to load the PDF anyways to do the highlighting, or do I miss something?

Comment: You can find an improved version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62819363/1729265).

Comment: Thanks @mkl, great piece of code. I just got an index out of bounce exception in TextPositionSequence.getWidth(). The class variable end is one too much. I fixed it by changing the second line to 

final TextPosition last = textPositions.get(end - 1);

(I haven't updated your post)

Comment: @DanielNorberg Thanks! Indeed, that was an error. After replacing `end` by `end-1`, though, you should additionally also check for `start == end` and explicitly return 0. Otherwise you run into trouble if `start` and `end` both are 0.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, yes I thought about that myself after I posted the last comment. Again, great example. I am investigating if it would be possible to insert forms to PDF with PDF box based on some anchors in an existing PDF file. Thanks to your code I have learnt how to get texts and their positions, I figure that texts are perfect anchors for this since you can pass information about field type, field width and other field data to PDF box this way and eventually replace the text with a form field. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is not an answer to your question but below is a skeleton example of how you would do this in `IText`. This is not saying the same is not possible in Pdfbox.

Basically you make a `RenderListener` that accepts the "parse events" as they happen. You pass this listener to `PdfReaderContentParser.processContent`. In the listener's `renderText` method you get all information you need to reconstruct the layout, including x/y coordinates and the text/image/... that make up the content.

```
RenderListener listener = new RenderListener() {
    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo arg0) {
        LineSegment segment = arg0.getBaseline();
        int x = (int) segment.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I1);
        // smaller Y means closer to the BOTTOM of the page. So we negate the Y to get proper top-to-bottom ordering
        int y = -(int) segment.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I2);
        int endx = (int) segment.getEndPoint().get(Vector.I1);
        log.debug("renderText "+x+".."+endx+"/"+y+": "+arg0.getText());
        ...
    }

    ... // other overrides
};

PdfReaderContentParser p = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    log.info("handling page "+i);
    p.processContent(i, listener);
}
```

Comment: actually in the pdf file the string is like ____${datefield}_____________ but i nead the coordinates of ${datefield} . is there any way to get those coordinates ?

Comment: Have a look at `TextRenderInfo.getCharacterRenderInfos()`. This method provides detail useful if a listener needs access to the position of each individual glyph in the text render operation.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for highlighting different words in a PDF file. For doing this, I need to know properly the word coordinates, so what I'm doing is getting the (x, y) coordinate from the top-left, from the first letter, and the (x, y) coordinate from the last letter from the top-right.

Later on, save the points in one array. Keep in mind that for getting properly the y coordinate you need the relative position in respect to the page size, because of the coordinate given. But the `getYDirAdj()` method is absolute and lots of time does not match with the one in the page.

```
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
    boolean isFound = false;
    float posXInit  = 0, 
          posXEnd   = 0, 
          posYInit  = 0,
          posYEnd   = 0,
          width     = 0, 
          height    = 0, 
          fontHeight = 0;
    String[] criteria = {"Word1", "Word2", "Word3", ....};

    for (int i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
        if (string.contains(criteria[i])) {
            isFound = true;
        } 
    }
    if (isFound) {
        posXInit = textPositions.get(0).getXDirAdj();
        posXEnd  = textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getXDirAdj() + textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getWidth();
        posYInit = textPositions.get(0).getPageHeight() - textPositions.get(0).getYDirAdj();
        posYEnd  = textPositions.get(0).getPageHeight() - textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getYDirAdj();
        width    = textPositions.get(0).getWidthDirAdj();
        height   = textPositions.get(0).getHeightDir();

        System.out.println(string + "X-Init = " + posXInit + "; Y-Init = " + posYInit + "; X-End = " + posXEnd + "; Y-End = " + posYEnd + "; Font-Height = " + fontHeight);

        float quadPoints[] = {posXInit, posYEnd + height + 2, posXEnd, posYEnd + height + 2, posXInit, posYInit - 2, posXEnd, posYEnd - 2};

        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = document.getPage(this.getCurrentPageNo() - 1).getAnnotations();
        PDAnnotationTextMarkup highlight = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

        PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
        position.setLowerLeftX(posXInit);
        position.setLowerLeftY(posYEnd);
        position.setUpperRightX(posXEnd);
        position.setUpperRightY(posYEnd + height);

        highlight.setRectangle(position);

        // quadPoints is array of x,y coordinates in Z-like order (top-left, top-right, bottom-left,bottom-right) 
        // of the area to be highlighted

        highlight.setQuadPoints(quadPoints);

        PDColor yellow = new PDColor(new float[]{1, 1, 1 / 255F}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
        highlight.setColor(yellow);
        annotations.add(highlight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
@Override
protected void writeString(String str, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
    TextPosition startPos = textPositions.get(0);
    TextPosition endPos = textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1);

    System.out.println(str + " [(" + startPos.getXDirAdj() + "," + startPos.getYDirAdj() + ") ,("
            + endPos.getXDirAdj() + "," + endPos.getYDirAdj() + ")]");

}
```

Output will look something like this 'String [(54.0,746.08) ,(99.71,746.08)]'