# Search texts and get position in pdf with java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How can I search for text and get position in pdf with java ? I tried with apache pdfbox and pdfclown but whenever the text goes down or start a new paragraph, it doesn't work. I want to get the same result like in the picture below.

Thank you.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbXir.png)

Comment: *How* did you try with apache pdfbox and pdfclown? It should be possible to implement a text-with-position search based on either library, so I would assume one can improve your attempts accordingly.

Comment: @mkl With pdfclown, I followed their guide to highlight text [here](https://pdfclown.org/resources/code-samples/text-highlighting/) and with apache pdfbox I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35987635/11737941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You referred to [one of my earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35987635/1729265) as an example for PDFBox which did not work for you. Indeed, as already explained in that answer it was a surprise to see that code match anything beyond single words as the callers of the routine overridden there gave the impression of calling it word-by-word. Thus, anything spanning more than a single line indeed hardly could be expected to be found.

But one can improve that example in quite a natural manner to allow searches across line borders, assuming lines are split at spaces. Replace the method `findSubwords` by this improved version:

```
List<TextPositionSequence> findSubwordsImproved(PDDocument document, int page, String searchTerm) throws IOException
{
    final List<TextPosition> allTextPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
    {
        @Override
        protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
        {
            allTextPositions.addAll(textPositions);
            super.writeString(text, textPositions);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeLineSeparator() throws IOException {
            if (!allTextPositions.isEmpty()) {
                TextPosition last = allTextPositions.get(allTextPositions.size() - 1);
                if (!" ".equals(last.getUnicode())) {
                    Matrix textMatrix = last.getTextMatrix().clone();
                    textMatrix.setValue(2, 0, last.getEndX());
                    textMatrix.setValue(2, 1, last.getEndY());
                    TextPosition separatorSpace = new TextPosition(last.getRotation(), last.getPageWidth(), last.getPageHeight(),
                            textMatrix, last.getEndX(), last.getEndY(), last.getHeight(), 0, last.getWidthOfSpace(), " ",
                            new int[] {' '}, last.getFont(), last.getFontSize(), (int) last.getFontSizeInPt());
                    allTextPositions.add(separatorSpace);
                }
            }
            super.writeLineSeparator();
        }
    };
    
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    stripper.setStartPage(page);
    stripper.setEndPage(page);
    stripper.getText(document);

    final List<TextPositionSequence> hits = new ArrayList<TextPositionSequence>();
    TextPositionSequence word = new TextPositionSequence(allTextPositions);
    String string = word.toString();

    int fromIndex = 0;
    int index;
    while ((index = string.indexOf(searchTerm, fromIndex)) > -1)
    {
        hits.add(word.subSequence(index, index + searchTerm.length()));
        fromIndex = index + 1;
    }

    return hits;
}
```

*([SearchSubword](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/SearchSubword.java#L129) method)*

Here we collect all `TextPosition` entries, we actually even add virtual such entries representing a space whenever a line break is added by PDFBox. As soon as the whole page is rendered, we search the collection of all these text positions.

Applied to the [example document](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/Variables.pdf) in the original question,

[image]

looking for `"${var 2}"` now returns all 8 occurrences, also those split across lines:

```
* Looking for '${var 2}' (improved)
  Page 1 at 164.39648, 257.65997 with width 37.078552 and last letter '}' at 195.62, 257.65997
  Page 1 at 188.75699, 273.74 with width 37.108047 and last letter '}' at 220.01, 273.74
  Page 1 at 167.49583, 289.72998 with width 40.55017 and last letter '}' at 198.74, 289.72998
  Page 1 at 176.67778, 305.81 with width 38.059418 and last letter '}' at 207.89, 305.81
  Page 1 at 164.39648, 357.28998 with width -46.081444 and last letter '}' at 112.46, 372.65
  Page 1 at 174.97762, 388.72998 with width -56.662575 and last letter '}' at 112.46, 404.09
  Page 1 at 153.74, 420.16998 with width -32.004005 and last letter '}' at 112.46, 435.65
  Page 1 at 162.99922, 451.61 with width -43.692017 and last letter '}' at 112.46, 467.21
```

The negative widths occur because the x coordinate of the end of the match is less than that of its start.