# PdfBox - changing font color in rectangle

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to find certain text in a pdf and making the font color white. As a POC I've already succeeded finding text and highlighting it in the pdf based on the code written by mkl here: [find position of text in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792228/search-texts-and-get-position-in-pdf-with-java/62819363#62819363)

Is it however possible, based on the received coordinates to change the font color of the text inside the  rectangle instead of highlighting the text? Alternatively, can I add a white rectangle to cover the text?

Thanks in advance

edit: I have started adding the rectangles to the pdf, however as stated they are not in correct position. This is what I have so far (don't mind the style, just a POC):

[TextPositionSequence class by mkl](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/593799fdecff174d5f4e127804d02d95a502b4d1/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/TextPositionSequence.java#L15)

```
byte[] content = ...;
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(content);
for (int page = 1; page <= document.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
            List<TextPositionSequence> hits = null;
            try {
                hits = findSubwordsImproved(document, page, "[" + searchTerm + "]");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (TextPositionSequence hit : hits) {
                TextPosition lastPosition = hit.textPositionAt(hit.length() - 1);
                TextPosition firstPosition = hit.textPositionAt(0);

                PDPage actualPage = document.getPage(page - 1);

                PDRectangle cropBox = actualPage.getCropBox();

                float x = firstPosition.getTextMatrix().getTranslateX() + cropBox.getLowerLeftX();
                float y = firstPosition.getTextMatrix().getTranslateY() + cropBox.getLowerLeftY();
                float w = hit.getWidth();
                try {
                    PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, actualPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);
                    contents.setNonStrokingColor(Color.RED);
                    contents.addRect(x, y, w, firstPosition.getHeight());
                    contents.fill();
                    contents.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
}
```

Comment: it is possible to change the color of text but it's not trivial. Adding white rectangles covering the text is much easier. In both cases, though, one can still successfully search the hidden text and copy&paste it.

Comment: It is okay that one can still copy/paste the hidden text. Any chance you can point me in the right direction for white rectangle? At the moment I'm getting a blank page with a rectangle at the last text location, lol. I'll tinker a bit further myself too

Comment: I can already add the rectablges over the text. However, the rectangles are not in the correct position. I've already looked at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080131/text-coordinates-when-stripping-from-pdfbox[link], but using the cropbox doesn't help

Comment: *"I can already add the rectablges over the text. However, the rectangles are not in the correct position."* - ok, that's a start. Please share you pivotal code. Maybe we can fix the coordinates easily.

Comment: I've edited the question with the code I currently have

Comment: Apparently the trick was to add resetcontext true and don't use the textmatrix.getTranslate methods. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't use the `getTranslate` methods, you are likely to run into trouble as soon as you process PDFs with page rotation.

Comment: oh good to know, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with the following code. I fiddled with the rectangle height a bit to get the box to cover the entire text. This might need tweaking in the future:

```
float posXInit = hit.getX();
float posXEnd = lastPosition.getXDirAdj() + lastPosition.getWidth();
float posYInit = firstPosition.getPageHeight() - firstPosition.getYDirAdj();
float posYEnd = firstPosition.getPageHeight() - lastPosition.getYDirAdj();
float height = firstPosition.getHeight();

PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, actualPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false, true);
contents.setNonStrokingColor(Color.WHITE);
contents.addRect(posXInit, posYEnd - height / 3, hit.getWidth(), height * 2);
contents.fill();
contents.close();
```

Comment: Please be aware that the text can still be extracted, i.e. drawing a white rectangle is not a secure redaction method if you want to hide confidential text.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The use case here was just to make it white