Search & Highlight Text On PDF File
How to search and highlight on pdf file in Java Android in a basic way and not use a third-party library that does charge for this feature. I have found a way to do it but couldn't apply it yet, to locate the pdf word then highlight it on top of it so the original file won't be affected then save annotation info separately.
I also have this method in java that I started working on:
    public void searchAndHighlight(String text, String fileName) {

    //Create a PdfDocument instance
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

    //Load a PDF sample document
    pdf.loadFromFile(fileName);

    PdfTextFind[] result = null;
    for (Object pageObj : pdf.getPages()) {
        PdfPageBase page =(PdfPageBase)pageObj;
        //Find text
        result = page.findText(text, false).getFinds();
        for (PdfTextFind find : result) {
            //Highlight searched text
            find.highLight();
        }
    }

    //Save the result file
    pdf.saveToFile(editedFileName);
    pdfRendererView.initWithFile(new File(getFilesDir(), editedFileName));

}

using this library
    implementation group:'e-iceblue',name:'spire.doc',version:'11.5.5'

but upon running the app, it's showing this error
cannot access Printable
class file for java.awt.print.Printable not found


AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.internal.Ge: Method name 'spr﻿—' in class 'com.spire.doc.packages.sprgaa' cannot be represented in dex format.","sources":[{"file":".gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/e-iceblue/spire.doc/11.5.5/c2797a752513880b16cf97c14603dc6c0d9d3d69/spire.doc-11.5.5.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}


    error: cannot access Printable
        pdf.loadFromFile(fileName);
           ^
  class file for java.awt.print.Printable not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error


"it's showing this error" -- that library is not designed for use on Android, apparently.

Try this Android port of another library for PDF's https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

So this library should not be used on Android?

I've viewed the library @Andrew but didn't know how to highlight and search, can you please provide some context on how to do it?

So Android does not come with a full implementation of the awt (Abstract Window Toolkit) library because it uses it's own graphics/windowing library. So any libraries that depend on awt are a problem. PDFBox has many sample and answers on stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/a/35987635/2373819 which even has a secondary answer that shows how to highlight

You should use the android version of Spire.PDF: Spire.PDF for Android via Java 

can someone please provide a full answer for the question when it comes to loading the library and using it on android in java
